# Is it a bad practice to use html tags in Model (MVC)?

Tags: java, html, servlets, model-view-controller, controller

It is well known that creating variables or putting logic in the View (MVC) is a very bad practice, so my question is quite the opposite, is it a bad practice to create view components (use html tags) in the Model (MVC) ?

Sometimes, a simple loop is not enough in my View and I need to use recursive function in order to convert my node of "tree" to a string object in my Model, then print the string object in the View. So I admit, I generate html tags in my Model even if there's always a way to convert a tree to list then send a "loop-able" list to the View.

But there's a second reason for me to create html components in my Model, because it is easier when I change framework, I do not need to convert my View to another format (.jsp , .xhtml for Facelets, ...).

=> Is it a really bad practice to use html tags in the Model (MVC) ? Why ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are choosing a particular way of representing your model data (html) because it is *easier*. That is a very bad decision and goes completely against the MVC pattern.

You can, however, do it properly very *easily*. Use `xml`! It would then be very simple to use an `xslt` transform from the `xml` to `html` in your view. You will be amazed how much easier it will be to make changes in the view without messing with the model.

> Is it a really bad practice to use html tags in the Model (MVC) ? Why ?

Every piece of software evolves. The requirements change, features are added, even the architecture changes. By using `html` to represent your data when transferring it between the model and the view makes change much more difficult.

Say for example, it is decided that the lovely report you have written which is  rendered into `html` by the model and presented directly to the browser by the view now needs to be generated in `csv` as well (a real requirement I was tasked with recently). See how difficult that would be? You would then be transforming your data from `html` to `csv`.

If, however, you had created your report in `xml` and implemented your view as applying an `xslt` to it to convert it into `html`, the need to present `csv` is trivial. It's just another `xslt`.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you intend to adhere to MVC model, keeping View information in the Model is definitely not part of it.

What if you want to send data over the network as JSON to a mobile application? What if you need to integrate with another system that doesn't display the data, but only processes it? Suddenly you've got some unnecessary extra data in the model that you'll need to strip before sending.